# C# Extension method on List with specific type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, type-conversion, extension-methods

I have the following 2 extension methods

```
namespace Services.Resources.Extensions
{
    public static class DataMapExtensions
    {
        public static T ToDTO<T>(this BaseModel model)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<T>(model);
        }

        public static List<T> ToDTO<T>(this List<BaseModel> models)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<List<T>>(models);
        }

    }
}
```

The first method works perfectly fine.

```
//Note: FlightRoute inherits BaseModel
FlightRouteDTO foo = new FlightRoute().ToDTO<FlightRouteDTO>(); //This works!
```

However, the second method does not seem to work.

```
List<FlightRouteDTO> bar = new List<FlightRoute>().ToDTO<FlightRouteDTO>(); //This doesn't work!
```

The compiler is saying

> Error  CS1929  'List< FlightRoute>' does not contain a definition for 'ToDTO' and the best extension method overload 'DataMapExtensions.ToDTO< FlightRouteDTO>(List< BaseModel>)' requires a receiver of type 'List< BaseModel>'

But `FlightRoute` is of type `BaseModel`. If I change the type of `bar` to explicitly be `List<BaseModel> ...` then the problem goes away.

```
List<FlightRouteDTO> bar = new List<BaseModel>().ToDTO<FlightRouteDTO>(); //Why does it only work this way?
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You can't directly call an extension method taking a List<BaseModel> with an instance of List<FlightRoute>, even if FlightRoute inherits from BaseModel.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why not. If I change the argument to be a generic List<V> and say that type V inherits from BaseModel, then that works. But I would think List<DerivedType> should also work since the inheritance still exists

Comment: You should read about covariance - it will explain why you can't assign `List<TDerived>` to `List<TBase>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's just the expected behavior: you are trying to use a `List<FlightRoute>` as a `List<BaseModel>`, but just because `FlitghtRoute` inherits from `BaseModel` doesn't make `List<FlitghtRoute>` inherit from `List<BaseModel>`: they are completely different types.

What you could do, instead, is to leverage the use of [Covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance), using interfaces instead of concrete types.

By changing your method signature to the following, you will notice that no compiler error will be generated:

```
public static List<T> ToDTO<T>(this IEnumerable<BaseModel> models)
{
    return Mapper.Map<List<T>>(models);
}
```

That's because `IEnumerable<T>` is an interface with a *covariant* type parameter. By looking at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ienumerable.cs.html#https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ienumerable.cs.html), you will notice that this interface is declared with `out T` as generic type parameter, which indicates that `T` is covariant, and may be replaced by any inherited type when we use `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Wow, I was actually surprised this worked. I think this approach is better than adding a second generic type.

Comment: Note that it's better to return `List<T>` in this case, because automapper will return `List<T>` anyway.

Comment: @Evk Agreed. I didn't remember which type automapper creates behind the scenes. Better to return a more specific type in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You could introduce a second type parameter with a constraint:

```
public static List<T> ToDTO<T, K>(this List<K> models) where K : BaseModel
{
    return Mapper.Map<List<T>>(models);
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Just not sure why I cant have List<BaseModel> since the type inheritance constraint should still exist with the derived type

Answer (score 2):

A better way to solve this might be to change signature like this:

```
public static List<T> ToDTO<T>(this IEnumerable<BaseModel> models)
{
    return Mapper.Map<List<T>>(models);
}
```

You don't really need to accept a `List`, because you are not doing anything "list-specific" with the value, and AutoMapper understands any "collection" type you pass to it. `IEnumerable<T>` is enough, and because it's covariant with respect to `T`, it now works fine in your case:

```
// works
List<FlightRouteDTO> bar = new List<FlightRoute>().ToDTO<FlightRouteDTO>();
```